# Why plotshape outside box?

Tags: pine-script

I need plotshape only inside the box. The script ignores the left border of the box.
How to fix it?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Ex", "", true)

// functions
func_1() =>
    (close < hl2[1] and close[1] < close[2]) ? 1 : 0

// Box
var box_level = box.new(na, na, na, na, extend= extend.right, bgcolor = color.new(color.gray, 90), border_color = na)
box.set_lefttop(box_level, bar_index[300], 25700)
box.set_rightbottom(box_level, bar_index, 15000)

// Condition - plotshape inside box
high_ = box.get_top(box_level)
low_ = box.get_bottom(box_level)
left_ = math.min(box.get_left(box_level), box.get_right(box_level))

rr = 0
if close > low_ and close < high_ and bar_index > left_
    rr := 1

plotshape(func_1() ? rr : na, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.lime, location=location.belowbar, title="Bull", size=size.small)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFJBt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is not actually plotting outside the box.

Vertically: the shapes themselves may be outside the box, but the condition is for the `close` to be within the box, and the script only plots the shape when close satisfies that condition. `location=location.belowbar` just places the shape somewhat below the bar, which may happen to be outside the box if `close` is near the border of the box.

Horizontally:  the left border of the box is `bar_index[300]`, so it is moving to the right every new bar. When `plot` is plotting historical bars on each bar `bar_index > left_` part of the condition is always true, because `left_` is equal to  `bar_index[300]`.  You can run bar replay to check this.